# EventManager in silverlight app

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

When trying to use the following

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox),
TextBox.GotFocusEvent,
new RoutedEventHandler(TextBox_GotFocus));
```

I am getting an error on 2nd parameter:
"'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'GotFocusEvent'"

Any help how to resolve this?

I am in the process of adding "Select All" behaviour for all TextBox in my silverlight app and by having this at Application_Startup in App.xaml.cs I thought would do the trick.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find an EventManager class in the Silverlight documentation?

I'm fairly sure that Silverlight does not support Class Handlers.

The closest you are going to get is to place a handler for `GotFocus` on some element that contains these TextBoxes and test the `OriginalSource` property to see if it is of type `TextBox`.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't.
The actual need for me to do this was that so that on GotFocus I could atuoscroll the page into viewing area on the screen. (I was going to write a function for that in TextBox_GotFocus) but I guess thats out of the question now...

Comment: the link below describes how you can add the functionality on the Got_Focus to autoscroll the page:

http://betaforums.silverlight.net/forums/p/130813/326335.aspx

Comment: Cool, glad you found a solution, although I wouldn't have used the RootVisual to find the transfom but rather the ScrollViewer itself, that way those magic numbers taking into account header and footer size would not have been needed.

Comment: I wasn't clear above, I don't have a solution for this.
That link above was the solution I would've used *if I had EventManager to use.
I am not sure of another way to capture Got_Focus of all the textboxes in my app.
If you know of one or can point me into right direction for this, that would be much appreciated :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TextBox doesn't define the static member `GotFocusEvent` but UIElement does.

Try replacing `TextBox` with `UIElement` like so:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox),
UIElement.GotFocusEvent,
new RoutedEventHandler(TextBox_GotFocus));
```

Comment: Hi Arc, I tried you suggestion to change it to UIElement, and it is still the same error [UIElement does not contain a definition for'GotFocusEvent'] 
Any other suggestions?

Comment: in Silverlight 2, we can't declare a routed event. What am I suppose to do to solve the problem described above (regarding select all)? 
thanks